# Rails: difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, model, accessor

What is the difference? Also, why does this not work:

The variables such as base_path are not being set.

```
class Cvit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :species,:program,:textup,:e_value,:filter,:min_identity,:cluster_dist,:fileup_file_name
  attr_accessor :base_path, :fa_file, :text_file, :dbase, :source, :bl_file, :bl_sorted, :gff_file, :cvt_file, :db, :overlay_coords_gray

  def initilize(*args)
     super(*args)
  end

  def cvitSetup()
    self.base_path = "blast_cvit/"
    self.fa_file = "input.fa"
    .
    .
  end
end
```

in the rails console the attributes get set correctly however when I try to do this:

controller:

```
def show
    @cvit = Cvit.find(params[:id])
    @cvit.cvitSetup()
    @cvit.blast()
    @cvit.generateGff()
    @cvit.generateCvitImage()


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @cvit }
    end
  end
```

and in my view I reference @cvit.some_attribute.html_safe but that attribute is null so I get an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`attr_accessor` creates the getter `method.attribute` and setter `method.attribute=` for the specified attributes.

`attr_accessible` is from ActiveRecord::Base and "Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment." See documentation and example [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible).

EDIT:

As for your second question, I don't know. I tried this dummy code and it worked:

```
class Test
attr_accessor :base_path, :fa_file
  def cvitSetup()
    self.base_path = "blast_cvit/"
    self.fa_file = "input.fa"
  end
end
t = Test.new
t.cvitSetup
p t.base_path
#=> "blast_cvit/"
```

Are you sure that you properly instantiated your class?

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` simply creates a getter-setter method for an attribute.

attr_accessible specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment, such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes), or attributes=(attributes). This has been excerpted from the link [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class)