# Rails 4 upgrading - attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I'm upgrading my application from rails 3.2 to rails 4.2.5.

In one of my model i have attr_accessor :user_id and i have defined a getter and setter methods, as i need to value on conditional basic.

```
    class DummyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

        attr_accessor :user_id
        belongs_to :current_user
        before_save :set_user_id

        def user_id
            self[:user_id] ? self[:user_id] : current_user_id ? current_user.id : nil
        end

        def user_id=(value)
            self[:user_id] = value ? value : current_user_id ? current_user.id : nil
        end

        private

        def set_user_id
            self.current_user_id = CurrentUser.first_or_create(:user_id => self[:user_id]).id
        end
    end
```

In the above DummyModel, that table doesn't have user_id. But a referance current_user_id which needs to be update by the params user_id which i get from browser.

So when i do DummyModel.new(params[:dummy_model]), it will try to assign the params[:dummy_model][:user_id] to the attr_accessor (With the setter method = user_id=(value)). Once assigned it can be used in the before_save.

This whole thing was working properly in rails 3.2. But when i tried to update to rails 4.2, im getting this error message, as assigning value for attr_accessor with self[:user_id] syntax is removed.

```
    ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_id`
```

So i have one solution to rename the user_id to something else, but user_id is used is many places of my application its not possible to change.

Hope this explains my problem. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you show your full model with all `attr_accessible`, `attr_accessor`, associations and getters/setters definitions?

Comment: I think answer below from @FrederickCheung is correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this but there's no point using attr_accessor if you're going to replace the methods it is generating. You may as well use the instance variable directly, for example

```
def user_id
  @user_id || current_user_id
end

def user_id=(value)
  @user_id = value || current_user_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer attr_accessible, you could use it in Rails 4 too. You should install it like gem:

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

What i can understand from the above but in rails 4 now there are strong parameters. attr_accessor still can be initialized in rails 4 and that still gives you virtual attributes, but from above it looks like user_id is a physical attribute on the model level. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply muaaz. I tried using protected_attributes too. My problem is using self[:user_id] instead of self.user_id. I cant use self.user_id because it will throw me stack level deep error.

Comment: Can you give me the error and have tried in that scope, plus whats the model name that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about [rails 3 attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) and [attr_accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby).

Link about difference between them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958433/1306709

In rails 4 you still can use `attr_accessor`, but if you meant `attr_accessible` here is some info: [strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371364/1306709)